# Is it necessary to have to install so many org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia files?

Tags: nvidia, updates, 22.04

I noticed that there are now many Nvidia-related files that needed installation after a system update and they are all quite sizable. Is this necessary?

[image: issue]